# how to have HTTP response with pipe throwing error?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, pipe, httpresponse

I have a nestjs application in which I created a pipe to check if the value is a valid URL.
If the URL is invalid, throw an error.  This is used in a controller to save an item into the database.

I just realized the pipe would throw 500 with Internal Server Error, I had to check the server log to see if it's actually from the pipe.

I wonder if there's a way that we can have an HTTP response directly with the message?

The pipe code I have is...

```js
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ValidUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(website: string) {
    if (website === '') return website;

    const validProtocols = ['http:', 'https:'];

    const { protocol } = new URL(website);
    if (validProtocols.includes(protocol)) {
      return website;
    }

    throw new BadRequestException(`invalid website value: ${website}`);
  }
}
```

the controller using the pipe looks like

```js
  @Post()
  create(
    @Body('website', ValidUrlPipe) website: string,
    @Body() createTvDto: CreateTvDto,
    @CurrentUser() user: User,
  ) {
    return this.televisionsService.create(user._id, createTvDto);
  }
```

Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions/solutions.

[image]

EDIT: I added an image of the error thrown by using Postman to call the endpoint

Comment: Why would it throw a 500? `BadRequestException` from `@nestjs/common` should map to an `HTTP 400` unless you have a custom exception filter not properly handling it.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I don't recall having custom exception, do you have any examples as I am quite new with nestjs, playing around with it to try understand more.  PS, I uploaded an image using postman calling the endpoint and the error thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dora, let me help you with the actual solution:

```
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ValidUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(website: string) {
    if (website === '') return website;

    const validProtocols = ['http:', 'https:'];

    try {
      const { protocol } = new URL(website);
      if (validProtocols.includes(protocol)) {
        return website;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Maybe add another bit of logging here for your own records if it is of interest?
      throw new BadRequestException(`invalid website value: ${website}`);
    }
  }
}
```

**For those of you privileged with Node 20:**

Instead of wrapping it all in a try/catch, you could use the static method URL.canParse().

Implemented for your pipe:

```
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ValidUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(website: string) {
    if (website === '') return website;

    const validProtocols = ['http:', 'https:'];

    if (URL.canParse(website)) { 
       // URL.canParse(...) returns a boolean if the url is valid or not
       const { protocol } = new URL(website);
       if (validProtocols.includes(protocol)) {
         return website;
       }
    }
    throw new BadRequestException(`invalid website value: ${website}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm more of a visual guy.  So I replaced the error thrown in the wrong place.  Thx thx

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the `new URL()` call is throwing an exception. You can wrap that in a `try/catch` block to transform it to the proper `BadRequestException` you are wanting to throw. Otherwise, I'd probably just use a simple regex `/https?:\/\//.test(website)` to validate that the passed website is indeed an HTTP or HTTPS website.

Comment: sryz this might be out of my knowledge....but if I am passing in random url 'adsf' catch will show in terminal the error but the process would continue (url is not required in db but if it's entered url needs to be validated) sryz for my old mind but I am used to if catch then `req.json` or `req` something so now it cannot throw customize to the user...and throwing 500.  How can I customize this?

Answer (score 0):

this line `const { protocol } = new URL(website);` will throw an error if the `website` parameter is not a valid URL. you could put validation to check if the parameter is a valid URL. it's better to have a try/ catch block to catch errors and return proper exceptions.